# Execute Terminal commands from Firemonkey (Android)

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

Just as the question says, can you run terminal commands from a Firemonkey application on Android? Also, if possible, can you retrieve the output?

Some code would be nice as I can't find anything on this...

PS: rooting is not a problem.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You can use [Android Debug Bridge](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb.html) to send commands to a device, including various [shell commands](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/shell.html#shellcommands).

Comment: Why the downvote?
Ken: Commands like a simple ls, rm, chown etc. And I'm talking about a rooted Android device
Remy: I want to execute the commands from my own android application, like you would with a command prompt emulator in delphi... call it a terminal clone if you will. I wouldn't mind embedding something in the app as long as it's standalone - won't require a usb cable or anything, just install the apk and execute the commands by any means possible.